# last 4 weeks records group by week

Tags: sql, records

How to get count (last 4 weeks records and week range) group by week range?

Week range means 22-28, 15-21,8-14, 1-7

I tried this

```
SELECT WEEK(PERIOD), SUM(CLICKS)
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
 GROUP BY WEEK(PERIOD)
```

and

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS period,
       SUM(clicks) AS clicks
  FROM `tablename`
 WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
 GROUP BY period
```

Comment: Looks like you're using MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean last 4 weeks by exactly each 7 x 24 days prior to today, up to the second, then

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '8-14 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                    THEN 'up to 7 days ago'
               END WeekPeriod, IFNULL(SUM(CLICKS),0) TotalClicks
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '08-14 days ago'
               WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                    THEN '01 to 7 days ago'
               END
 ORDER BY WeekPeriod
```

Comment: To get the values in order according to week and if count of id is 0, it should give value as 0. For this what i can do?

Comment: actually this month, there is no record in the table. while this it is giving the results like aug, sep, oct only. is there any possibility to give nov without records  also?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myTable table 
(
    id bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered 
    , createdDate date not null
    , clicks int not null
)

insert @myTable
      select GETUTCDATE() - 00, 9
union select GETUTCDATE() - 01, 6
union select GETUTCDATE() - 02, 5
union select GETUTCDATE() - 03, 9
union select GETUTCDATE() - 04, 3
union select GETUTCDATE() - 05, 6
union select GETUTCDATE() - 06, 3
union select GETUTCDATE() - 07, 6
union select GETUTCDATE() - 08, 9
union select GETUTCDATE() - 09, 9
union select GETUTCDATE() - 10, 8
union select GETUTCDATE() - 11, 7
union select GETUTCDATE() - 12, 1
union select GETUTCDATE() - 13, 2
union select GETUTCDATE() - 14, 5
union select GETUTCDATE() - 15, 3
union select GETUTCDATE() - 16, 8
union select GETUTCDATE() - 17, 7
union select GETUTCDATE() - 18, 4

select DATEPART(week, createdDate) Period
, SUM(clicks) ClickSum
from @myTable
group by DATEPART(week, createdDate)
order by Period
```

Comment: actually i have to get last 4 month's names from table 

for this i have used this query 

select MONTHNAME(submitdate) as m from survey where submitdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submitdate) 
 

that answer is like this 


m
August
September
October


but here what happens is if the month have no records, its not dipslaying in the result how i can solve this?

Comment: right outer join with a selection of months maybe - that ensures you'll have a result for each month, but sometimes with no data.  If you need a code sample please post this as a separate question, referencing this one with a link; that will avoid scope creep on this question / should make it easier for future readers to find the answers they're after.  If you chuck a link to your new post in the comments here I'll take a look - though someone will probably beat me to it.